# min and max loading of css and js on page load

Tags: javascript, html, css, dhtml

My company has its own sales crm they have minimum of 300 web pages, can some on suggest on

1) Number of css and js files to be loaded on pageload.
 2) Max number of http request for page load.
 3) Size of index page.
 4) User wait time for first time.

Thank You
 http://www.momeen.com

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you think your users will put up with. Different user groups for different web sites all have wildly varying expectations.

As a general guide I would say that after 4 seconds your users will get impatient, after 10 seconds they'll probably give up.

Once you've worked out what you've considered acceptable, you will be able to come up with some answers for your first 3 questions. If it's too slow, reduce the number of css/js files, or spread them across different domains (or use a CDN), or combine and minify them. There are no definitive answers for your question.

Answer (score 1):

> Number of css and js files to be loaded on pageload.?

There is no limit on it.You can add up as many as you like.
 But its better if you use less css/js files  because it accounts for your total loading time.
There are plenty of techniques that you can follow to save up those extra kbs.
Refer this:[Tips to save up our page load time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378821/tips-to-save-up-our-page-load-time)

```
 2) Max number of http request for page load.
```

No limit. But as the number of requests required to load a page grows, the time taken for the page to be rendered increases.

> 3) Size of index page & 4) User wait time for first time.

Size of index page --the minimum size possible without affecting the performance of page.

User wait time for first time-- < 4 seconds

[Is there a maximum size that web pages should be kept under?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430374/is-there-a-maximum-size-that-web-pages-should-be-kept-under)

**Always remember,Less is more**